slick slide issue where slides move one by one instead of all at once on mobile
I am using Slick Slide, and on PC, I can move multiple slides freely at once. However, on mobile width, it only moves one slide at a time. Does anyone know which code needs to be modified?
Current site: https://xn--h49al71aq4an8tdlb.com/NoMoreDev/#roadMap
Current code :
$('.roadMap-active2').slick({
    dots: false,
    infinite: false,
    speed: 500,
    autoplay: false,
    arrows: false,
    slidesToShow: 4,
    slidesToScroll: 4,
    rows: 1,
    swipeToSlide: true,
    touchMove: true,
    responsive: [
        {
            breakpoint: 1400,
            settings: {
                dots: false,
                infinite: false,
                speed: 500,
                autoplay: false,
                arrows: false,
                slidesToShow: 3.4,
                slidesToScroll: 4,
                rows: 1,
                swipeToSlide: true,
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint: 1200,
            settings: {
                dots: false,
                infinite: false,
                speed: 500,
                autoplay: false,
                arrows: false,
                slidesToShow: 3.4,
                slidesToScroll: 4,
                rows: 1,
                swipeToSlide: true,
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint: 992,
            settings: {
                dots: false,
                infinite: false,
                speed: 500,
                autoplay: false,
                arrows: false,
                slidesToShow: 2.7,
                slidesToScroll: 4,
                rows: 1,
                swipeToSlide: true,
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint: 767,
            settings: {
                dots: false,
                infinite: false,
                speed: 100,
                autoplay: false,
                arrows: false,
                slidesToShow: 1.2,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                rows: 1,
                swipeToSlide: true,
                touchMove: true,
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint: 575,
            settings: {
                dots: false,
                infinite: false,
                speed: 100,
                autoplay: false,
                arrows: false,
                slidesToShow: 1.2,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                rows: 1,
                swipeToSlide: true,
                touchMove: true,
            }
        },
    ]
});

What did you try : swipeToSlide, touchMove
were you expecting : I want to swipe through the slides freely on mobile as well.
